# Sending mail in php?

Tags: php, sendmail

I am send email using php mail() function.But it takes long time to receive to the user.It should receive with 10 minutes.how can i do that and why it is taking long time to receive more than 30 minutes its taking now.

Comment: its a server configuration issue and you can't do much about it...

Comment: ho..i am using dedicated server linux (Cpanel)how can i change server configurations

Comment: It also depends on the server queue. If there are also other e-mails to be sent, the size of the e-mails etc.

Comment: so any idea to sent email faster?

Comment: you can use PHPmailer with an gmail, it's safe and good :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't php it's the mail server.  Mails get put in a Queue and the server processes them one at a time.  So if you are sending lots of emails from the php script they build up and can take minutes, hours, days to be sent if you have enough built up in the queue.

Comment: He actually may use different server PEAR::Mail, http://email.about.com/od/emailprogrammingtips/qt/PHP_Email_SMTP_Authentication.htm

Comment: I agree he would be better off using a dedicated mail server IMO.  Webservers should be used for serving web pages not emails.